# Update Protobuf in Lambda

Tags: lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda function that uses python 3.8 runner to forward logs and metrics from aws to datadog. After running, when AWS Security Hub does audit, it gives me this finding with a high rating:

'A parsing vulnerability for the MessageSet type in the ProtocolBuffers versions prior to and including 3.16.1, 3.17.3, 3.18.2, 3.19.4, 3.20.1 and 3.21.5 for protobuf-cpp, and versions prior to and including 3.16.1, 3.17.3, 3.18.2, 3.19.4, 3.20.1 and 4.21.5 for protobuf-python can lead to out of memory failures. A specially crafted message with multiple key-value per elements creates parsing issues, and can lead to a Denial of Service against services receiving unsanitized input. We recommend upgrading to versions 3.18.3, 3.19.5, 3.20.2, 3.21.6 for protobuf-cpp and 3.18.3, 3.19.5, 3.20.2, 4.21.6 for protobuf-python. Versions for 3.16 and 3.17 are no longer updated.'

The fix is:

'Affected packages: Name - protobuf

Package manager PYTHONPKG

Installed version 4.21.2

Fixed version 4.21.6'.

How do I implement this fix? The lambda was created using cloudformation so there is just 1 file (index.py) in the zipped package but no visible or hidden files or dependences in the lambda environment. Where can I find the protobuf to update it?

tried to see if upgrading from python 3.8 to 3.9 will help but didnt think that will solve the issue

Comment: What packages are you importing?

Comment: No package is being imported. The index.py is empty